# What is this small hovering bird with a yellow throat, breast, and belly, and a brown back and head, found in the Philippines?

Tags: birds, bird-watching, bird-identification, philippines

What are these small birds in the Philippines that can hover like hummingbirds? They had yellow throats/necks, chests, bellies, slightly curved beaks, and brown backs and heads. They were only slightly bigger than a human thumb. They are not commonly spotted in the area where these pictures were taken.

I searched online and found a Wikipedia article about the [yellow-bellied whistler AKA Philippine whistler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow-bellied_whistler) (*Pachycephala philippinensis*), a bird that looks similar and is endemic to the Philippines. However, the [picture in the article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKkL0.jpg) showed a bird with a straight beak and no yellow throat. So I’m not sure if these birds are the same species or not.

These photos were taken on May 28, 2023, in a rural backyard located in Western Visayas, Philippines. The area is abundant with plants and trees. Due to the proximity of a typhoon, the weather was cloudy and windy, and it started raining shortly after these photos were taken. The birds seemed to be a couple, playing and hovering around a guyabano tree.

Photos of the birds hovering:

[image: photo of the birds described above]

[image]

[image]

Photos of the birds perched on a tree branch — there are two birds in each of the following three photos:

<sup>(Click/tap on an image thumbnail below to view the higher-resolution, original image.)</sup>

[image: photo of the two birds described above][image: photo of the two birds described above]

[image: photo of the two birds described above]

Cropped photos of the birds perched on a tree branch:

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sub>Click/tap on an image thumbnail below to view the higher-resolution, original image.</sub>

[image][image]

[image][image]

Comment: Maybe you can take away some of the photos, especially the second section does seem to have a lot of repeats.

Comment: @Willeke I’ve converted some of the images into image thumbnails that link to their higher-resolution original versions to significantly reduce the amount of space they occupy on the screen. I think I should include those photos in the post and not remove any more, so the birds can be seen from multiple views.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it is a female or possibly juvenile [olive-backed sunbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olive-backed_sunbird) (*Cinnyris jugularis*), based on pictures on the web. I ID'd it by searching "birds phillipines" in google and flicking through a couple of links. The distinguishing characteristics are the curved beak, olive-green back and the small pale bar over the eyes.

This is a common species of bird throughout SE Asia and even into Australia.